# Prefill name in dialog box opened using showOpenDialogSync() in Electron JS

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am opening a dialog box which allows the user to enter a folder name and then when he/she clicks ok, the folder is created at the specified location. So I want to provide a default name when the dialog box opens at first.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using showMessageBoxSync solves the issue.

It opens the folders in the path and when it cannot find any existing folder, it adds the remaining path to the user input box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the property (defaultPath:"path") to the option object passed into the showOpenDialogSync(options).

Comment: That will open that specified folder. But when that dialog box opens, it allows user to enter a name, so that name I want to be pre filled